# ECC memory understanding, need some notes to understand

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, operating-system

I got this question from some peer,

he told that there can be 2 bit error detection algos and that is ECC, but, he asked me read up on net but, where can i find it?

For example, if I have data- 10010011, then analyse data with ECC for 1-bit error detection and also for 2 bit error detection.

How should I approach this probllem?

Please, help me guide.

Comment: Read [ECC memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory) wikipage, then [forward error correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction). But your question is off-topic here and mistagged.

Comment: What is the right tag??

Comment: Your question does not belong to SO (which is for software questions related to some given source code)